# Showing that two short exact sequences are not equivalent

Tags: category-theory, modules

> Two short exact sequences of $R$-modules $0\rightarrow A \rightarrow C \rightarrow B \rightarrow 0$ and $0\rightarrow A \rightarrow C' \rightarrow B \rightarrow 0$ are equivalent if there is a map $\phi: C \rightarrow C'$ such that the diagram formed by these two sequences commutes.
>
> Show that if $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $A=B=\mathbb{Z}/(3)$, then there are three inequivalent short exact sequences.

My intuition from group theory tells me to consider $\mathbb{Z}/(3) \oplus \mathbb{Z}/(3)$ and $\mathbb{Z}/(9)$. Sequences with different maps between the modules are considered different sequences, so if I can find two homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}/(9)$ to $\mathbb{Z}/(3)$ (or from the direct sum to $\mathbb{Z}/(3)$), then I will be on the right track.

Is this the correct thinking, and does anyone have any hints for choosing my homomorphisms? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the middle must be an abelian group of order $9$, so indeed we have $\Bbb Z/(3)\times \Bbb Z/(3)$ and $\Bbb Z/(9)$ as candidates.

With $\Bbb Z/(3)\times \Bbb Z/(3)$ we have a split sequence and automatically a direct sum decomposition, i.e., $C=\Bbb Z/(3)\times \Bbb Z/(3)$ gives us only one equivalence class of s.e.s.

With $\Bbb Z/(9)$, pick a preimage $c$ of our favourite generator $1+(3)$ of $B$. Then all preimages are $c,c+3,c+6$. No matter which one we take, if we multiply it by $3$ in $\Bbb Z/9$, we arrive at $3c$, which must be in the image of $A$; and it is nonzero because otherwise $c\mapsto 0\in B$. But $3c$ may either be the image of $1+(3)\in A$ or of $2+(3)\in A$. These choices give us two inequivalent s.e.s., as desired.